# Run.reg file with Java

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to run reg files with Java. I tried this with no luck:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegEdit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//      Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("ihindi.reg"));

        String[] cmd = {"regedit", "ihindi.reg"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ihindi.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel]
"HomePage"=dword:00000001
```

When I run it, it doesn't make anything and errors. Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post the details of the errors that you're getting.

Comment: I don't get any errors. I also included my reg file now. I run the reg file and it works. But I can't run it via Java.

Comment: you probably need to explicitly set the working directory

Comment: Process won't, by itself, output anything, you need to read from its input stream and decide how you want to display it

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to add the "/s" statement in between, your process probably got disturb while you're writing the data into the regedit.
I was in the exactly same situation as yours, no error, but it just couldn't write into the regedit. the "/s" did the job.

```
try{
 // silence all the process without prompting the dialog box to ask if user wanna proceed.
     String[] cmd = { "regedit.exe", "/s", regFilePath};
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
     process.waitFor();
}catch (InterruptedException e){
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of problems with this. The following line:

```
String[] cmd = {"regedit", "ihindi.reg"};
```

should pass the full path to the `ihindi.reg` file, not just the file name.

Also,

It is possible that a dialog box is preventing that `waitFor()` call from ever returning.

You should call regedit with the `/s` switch to silence those dialog boxes.

Also, you might consider using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) like so:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RegEdit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//      Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("ihindi.reg"));

        //you will need to figure this out
        String ihindiPath = getIhindiPath();

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "/s", ihindiPath) 

        try {
            processBuilder.start().waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your paths, with your current code *.reg would have to be in the same directory as the jar file. You can however set the working directory explictly when usong `ProcessBuilder`:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "myreg.reg");
 pb.directory("c:/");//thus our file should be located in c:\myreg.reg
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved through Process Builder in JAVA. Please consider the following example for this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "reg_file_to_run.reg");
Process processToExecute = processBuilder.start();
```

And then you can optionally wait for the completion of process execution with this line:

```
processToExecute.waitFor();
```

Note: If command in your registry file asks for confirmation prompts while making changes in registry entries, you can perform it silently as well with *'/s'* option. Like this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("regedit", "/s", "reg_file_to_run.reg");
```

Withthis command would be executed silently without any confirmation prompt.